# Calculating Modulo of powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I am trying to solve 14<sup>2019<sup>2019</sup></sup> mod 60 without using a calculator.

To do this, I am using the logarithm:
a = b<sup>x</sup> -> x = log<sub>b</sub>a => 14<sup>2019<sup>2019</sup></sup> mod 60 => lg(14) a = 2019<sup>2019</sup> mod 60

a = 14<sup>2019<sup>2019</sup></sup> mod 60

2019<sup>2019</sup> mod 60

The problem is that gcd(2019, 60) = 3 and NOT 1. So I can't use Euler's Theorem.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hint: the modular powers of $14$ are $14,16,44,16,44,\cdots$ and $2019^{2019}$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chinese Remainder Theorem with $60 = 4 \times 15$.  Note that $\gcd(4,15) = 1$.

- $$14^{2019^{2019}} \equiv 2^{2019^{2019}} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$
- $$14^{2019^{2019}} \equiv (-1)^{2019^{2019}} \equiv -1 \pmod{15}$$

Therefore, $$14^{2019^{2019}} \equiv 44 \pmod{60}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $60 = 3 \times 4 \times 5$, so we can use Chinese remainder theorem (without this, the problem is difficult, since $60$ is a very large modulus, and $14^x$ is difficult to evaluate mod $60$ to find patterns).

Clearly, if $L = 14^{\left(2019^{2019}\right)}$ then $L \equiv 0 \mod 4$. Since $14 \equiv -1 \mod 3$ and $14 \equiv -1 \mod 5$, we have that $L \equiv (-1)^{\left(2019^{2019}\right)} = -1$ both mod $3$ and mod $5$.

Thus,$L \equiv 0 \mod 4, L \equiv -1 \mod 3, L \equiv -1 \mod 5$. By CRT, this determines $L \mod 60$, an it is not difficult to see that $L \equiv 44 \mod 60$.

NOTE : Below $60 = 4 \times 15$ has been used : this is also fine as CRT just requires a product of coprimes.